send object with GetFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable
Working with .net8.0 Blazor Web App with MinimalAPI and FastEndpoints.  Currently, to send an object to a get request that returns a list I'm using
        var req = new GetAgencyListRequest()
        {
            AgentLastName = _searchText,
            AgencyName = _searchText
        };

    using (var httpSvc = new HttpService(state))
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri(httpSvc.BaseAddress + "agency/AgencyList"),
                Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(req), Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json")
            };

        var response = await httpSvc.SendAsync(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception("Could not get Agency list");

        using (var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStream())
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
            _gridData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Agency>>(stream, options);
        }
    }

This works, but it seems like it could be simplified.  I found GetFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable, but can't find a way to send the request object.  I could pass as parameters, but I have other more complex requests so I want to use this method.
var uri = new Uri("agency/AgencyList");
var resp = httpSvc.GetFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable<Agency>(uri);

I can't find a way to send the object.
How do I send an object with this method?
Thank you

I came up with a few generic helper methods.
public static class HttpHelper
{
  public static async Task<List<T>> GetList<T>(StateContainer state, string route, object req)
  {
    using (var httpSvc = new HttpService(state))
    {
      var request = new HttpRequestMessage
      {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = new Uri(httpSvc.BaseAddress + route),
        Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(req), Encoding.UTF8,
                      "application/json")
      };

      var response = await httpSvc.SendAsync(request);

      if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw new Exception($"Could not get {typeof(T).Name} list");

      using (var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStream())
      {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(stream, options).ToList();
      }
    }
  }

  public static async Task<List<T>> GetList<T>(StateContainer state, string route)
  {
    using (var httpSvc = new HttpService(state))
    {
      var response = await httpSvc.GetAsync(route);

      if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw new Exception($"Could not get {typeof(T).Name} list");

      using (var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStream())
      {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(stream, options);
      }
    }
  }

  public static async Task<T> GetObject<T>(StateContainer state, string route, object req)
  {
    using (var httpSvc = new HttpService(state))
    {
      var request = new HttpRequestMessage
      {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = new Uri(httpSvc.BaseAddress + route),
        Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(req), Encoding.UTF8,
                      "application/json")
      };

      var response = await httpSvc.SendAsync(request);

      if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw new Exception($"Could not get {typeof(T).Name}");

      var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
      return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(responseStream,
          new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    }
  }

  public static async Task<T> GetObject<T>(StateContainer state, string route)
  {
    using (var httpSvc = new HttpService(state))
    {
      var response = await httpSvc.GetAsync(route);

      if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        var errorMsg = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        errorMsg = String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg) ? $"Could not get {typeof(T).Name}"
                    : GetErrorMessage(errorMsg);
        throw new Exception(errorMsg);
      }
      var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
      return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(responseStream,
          new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true })!;
    }
  }
  private static string GetErrorMessage(string message)
  {
    string errorText = "called! - ";

    string msg = message;
    int index = msg.IndexOf("\r\n");
    msg = msg.Substring(0, index);
    msg = msg.Substring(msg.IndexOf(errorText) + errorText.Length);
    return msg;
  }
}

So now all that's needed to get an object or list is
Agency _agency = await HttpHelper.GetObject<Agency>(state, $"agency/{AgencyID}");

Just pass in the Type and the route..Done!

The GET verb is typically is used for retrieving data, not sending it. For simple filters, you can include them in the URL query string.
To send objects in a request, you would typically use the POST verb, like PostAsJsonAsync:
var payload = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "jwt", jwtToken },
            { "refreshToken", refreshToken }
        };

var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Session/StartSession", payload);

Now, if you only want to send your filters to the GET request, use query string:
var requestUri = $"{httpSvc.BaseAddress}agency/AgencyList";
var queryString = $"?AgentLastName={Uri.EscapeDataString(_searchText)}&AgencyName={Uri.EscapeDataString(_searchText)}";
var fullUri = new Uri(requestUri + queryString);

using (var httpSvc = new HttpService(state))
{
    var response = await httpSvc.GetFromJsonAsyncEnumerable<Agency[]>(fullUri);
}


Thank you for your quick answer!  I'm using FastEndpoints which allows you to send a request object - or payload as you called it - and get a response.  Also, in the API, the request is received as that same object so no need for a dictionary.  In your first suggestion, I still have to make a dictionary and deserialize the response.  In the second, I have to make a long query string instead of a request object used by FastEndpoints.  I was hoping to call one method to send the request object and return an already converted list.

you can use an extension method targetting the HttpClient together with a custom union/results type, something like below:
public sealed class HttpResult<TResult>(
    TResult? result = default, 
    ProblemDetails? problems = default)
{
    public TResult? Result { get; } = result;
    public ProblemDetails? Problems { get; } = problems;

    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Result))]
    public bool IsSuccess => Result is not null;

    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Problems))]
    public bool IsProblem => Problems is not null;
}

public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<HttpResult<TResult>> SendRequest<TRequest, TResult>(
        this HttpClient client,
        HttpMethod method,
        string requestUri,
        TRequest? request = default,
        string contentType = "application/json")
    {
        var rsp = await client.SendAsync(
          new()
          {
              Method = method,
              RequestUri = new($"{client.BaseAddress}{requestUri.TrimStart('/')}"),
              Content = request is null
                            ? null
                            : new StringContent(
                                JsonSerializer.Serialize(request),
                                Encoding.UTF8,
                                contentType)
          });

        if (rsp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return new(await rsp.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TResult>());

        if (rsp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            return new(default, await rsp.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ProblemDetails>());

        return new();
    }
}

then you can conveniently send requests to the backend server like so:
var request = new GetAgencyListRequest
{
    AgencyName = "abc",
    AgencyLastName = "xyz"
};

var res = await client.SendRequest<GetAgencyListRequest, List<Agency>>(
              HttpMethod.Get,
              "/agencies/list",
              request);

if (res.IsSuccess)
{
    var agencies = res.Result;
}

if (res.IsProblem)
{
    var errors = res.Problems.Errors;
}

another alternative would be to use an http client library such as flurl.
